# Sublime text paste joined multicursor

Tags: plugins, cursor, sublimetext3, multiline, code-snippets

I am looking for a Sublime Text 3 plugin/snippet that allow me to paste a multicursor selection where lines are joined to eachother with a separator I am defining right away.
For example, let's say I have those lines in my clipboard:

`foo
bar
baz`

When pressing the command, it would be pasted, and I would have a multicursor selector between each item:

[image]

Then I can write my separator:

[image]

Additionally to separators, I could also set data in the beginning and in the end or each item:

[image]

[image]

and then, after pressing `tab`:

[image]

[image]

Ideally, pressing `tab` would circle on the different muticursors:

`separatorCursor <=> beginingCursor <=> endCursor`

Do you know any plugin that does what I'm looking for?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The absence of answers seemed to indicate that no such plugin exists yet, so I made my own.

https://github.com/OoDeLally/MultiCaretPaste

So far it only manage central separator. I don't know yet how to circle through TABs as indicated in my original post.